# Author Page in Wordpress work only when preview site

Tags: wordpress

My Author page in WordPress it's only working when I preview the page on Customize, but when I try to access it by URL it's a 404 error.
Here is the image of this:
*When I preview:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRhyu.png)

*When I try to access:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib7IU.png)

Can someone tell me why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is that your WP theme doesn’t have an Author Template (author.php) –so WordPress does not know what to show on your author page.

You can create a file named **author.php** and upload it in wp-content/themes/your-theme directory.